# Who can check in and deliver to the stream in a repo workspace? Only the owner?

Tags: rtc

1. In the RTC only owner of the Repository work space can check in the code ?
   Other members can only take updates by changing the flow target.
2. Can I provide access for more than one user in a repository work space (Multiple owners) to deliver the code.
3. If i create a scoped work space , other members can only view the changes and take updates from it. Is it correct?

Comment: Don't forget to accept answer for your past questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: You have now asked 6 questions but accepted only one: please review your questions, and, if you think they are appropriately answered, accept their answer. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) That will help others to know the question has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

> In the RTC only owner of the Repository work space can check in the code ?

Yes,  the idea is for an owner to not have the surprise, when coming in the morning, to discover his/her own repo workspace with new checkins or having done new deliver without his/her knowledge.

> Can I provide access for more than one user in a repository work space (Multiple owners) to deliver the code.

Not to deliver: you need to accept change set from that repo workspace, and publish said change sets from your very own repo workspace (that I recommend to be a scoped one, not a private one)

> If i create a scoped work space , other members can only view the changes and take updates from it. Is it correct.

Yes, but the natural flow is to deliver to the stream, or to accept change set from the stream (only one source).

You change that flow target to a colleague repo workspace only if you need it (ie, not every morning, but in the rare occurrence when that colleague has committed some interesting change set but has not deliver them to the stream yet).

The rest of the time, you sync your own (scoped) repo workspace only from the Stream.